# Cannot read connectionString from appsettings.json

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am creating a class library that needs to communicate with a Sqlite Database, using .NET Core and EF Core.

I'm executing my code from a Test Project in the same solution

The issue is `GetConnectionString()` always returns null.

My appsettings.json is

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "TestingDatabase": "Server=c:\\myDb.db;Version=3;"
    }
  }
```

And my Entities file is

```
  public Entities()
  {
      _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true,true)
            .Build();
  }

  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
  {
      var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("TestingDatabase"); // always returns null
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
  }
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: try to explore the `_configuration` while `OnConfiguring` is executed. Is there configuration entries you are expecting ? You said that it is the class library project. Is it possible that library appsettings configuration is overwritten by the exe configuration file ? Would you like to add one more class like `LibraryConfig` as external dependency and let the exe application to supply it for the library?

Comment: I am executing the class library via a testing project in the same solution. When you say explore, what do you mean. Is there any specific property I should be looking for? @oleksa

Comment: you can start `Debug test` under the `VS test explorer` and put a breakpoint in the `OnConfiguring ` method. Then you can add watch for `_configuration` (or move mouse over the name while breakpoint is hit and test execution was stopped. This will show you the `_configuration ` content. So you can check does the `AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")` actually work. Is `appsettings.json` copied to the test project output folder btw ? Probably it is not copied and this is the reason.

Comment: No... the `appsettings.json` is not in the `Tests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1` directory. Should it be? A quick check of .NET Framework shows the app.config is also not set to copy to output directory

Comment: Yes it is. You can copy `appsettings.json` manually and run the test one more time. `app.config` is renamed to `project.dll.config` and is copied by the VS for dependent projects usually. I have seen it is done many times.

Comment: hmmm... setting the `appsetting.json` file to Copy to ouput directory has fixed this. Do you want to move this to an answer @oleksa